# Find element by xpath in selenium, with partial match

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a code to find an element that looks like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@id='playerListPlayerId_9874']/td[7]/a").click()
```

Id like to be able to find it only using:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("tr[@id='playerListPlayerId_9874']").click()
```

But that does not work. I basically do not want to have to deal with the td[7]. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is just one link inside that table row you can use:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@id='playerListPlayerId_9874']//a").click()
```

---

If there are multiple links inside that table row you might need to add an id to the `<a>` element or a special `class` attribute and use that for selection:

*by id:*

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='THE_ID']").click()
```

*by class:*

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@id='playerListPlayerId_9874']//a[@class='THE_CLASS']").click()
```

*or if multiple classes are assigned:*

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@id='playerListPlayerId_9874']//a[contains(@class,'THE_CLASS'])]").click()
```

Comment: Tried doing that and got `[error] Element tr[@id='playerListPlayerId_9874']//a not found`

Comment: It is the only link inside the table row though

Comment: sorry I missed the `//` at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

If there are several links with the same xpath you might have to add an index as the result is a list:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@id='playerListPlayerId_9874']//a")[0].click()
```